# Is ARMV7s mandatory for app store publication?

Tags: app-store

I noticed that our application had became much bigger lately, partially due to the presence of multiple binaries.

I understand `arm64` is now mandatory, and `armv7` mandatory to support older models, but what about `armv7s` ? Can I safely remove it from my app, thus making it a few Mo lighter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `armv7s`. `armv7` and `arm64` are enough. In fact, in Xcode 6.2 these are now the Standard architectures. If that's not an endorsement, I don't know what is.

Comment: Actually, using standards arch setting also build armv7s

Comment: I'm looking at Xcode 6.2, and have just submitted an app with those architectures.

Comment: I believe you, and will accept your answer in a minute :)